# How to stop this algorithm without using return;

Tags: java, if-statement

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {

Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to Baugette Store! ");

System.out.println("*****Bakery Inventory*****");
System.out.print("Enter amount of Baugette:");
int amount1=scan.nextInt();
if(amount1<0) {
    System.out.println("Error.");
    return;
}
System.out.print("Enter Price of Baugette:");
double price1=scan.nextDouble();
*if(price1<0) {
    System.out.println("Error.");
    return;
}
System.out.println("**Customer Interface**");
System.out.println("Welcome to our baugette store. ");
System.out.println("We have "+price1+ " baugette(s) available.");
System.out.println("How Many Baugette(s) Do You Want to Buy?");
int amount2=scan.nextInt();
if(amount2<=0) {
    System.out.println("Error.");
return;
}
if(amount2>amount1) {
    System.out.println("Error.");
    return;
}
else {
System.out.println("You want to buy "+amount2+ " baugette(s).");
double totalcost,r;
totalcost=amount2*price1;
r=amount1-amount2;
System.out.println("Yours cost is "+(int)totalcost+" Turkish lira(s)");
System.out.println("Now, We have "+(int)r+" baugette(s) remaining.");
System.out.println("Thank you for shopping from Kolantro Baugette Shop today.");
System.out.println("Good bye :)");
}
}
}
```

I want to learn how do i stop this algorithm without using return; for each if block. When I delete all return;s complier keeps reading codes. I want to execute when i type -3 for first if block Algorithm must be stopped without using return;.

Comment: why "without using return"? Maybe you can use `if (...) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: `if (x) { y; return; } z;` is equivalent to `if (x) y; else z;`. Use this.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments below your question suggest, you can use a if-else-statement:

```
if (amount1 == -3) {
    return;
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Or short:

```
if (amount1 == -3) {
    return;
}

// ...
```

But this way you have a return, which you don't want if I understand you correctly. You can invert the logic and run your code only if the amount1 is not -3. This way there is no return-statement:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    // ...

    if (amount1 != -3) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you asked for -3 as an example, here is the code if you want to skip if the amount is below or equals 0:

```
    if (amount1 > 0) { // One ore more baugettes available, shop is open
        // ...
    }
```

Take your time to think about how if-statements work and how the condition(s) are evaluated. You can also nest if-statements:

```
if (1>0) {
    if (a==b) {
    }
}
```

This way you can structure your algorithms in a neat way.

---

Btw, you have a bug:

```
"We have " + price1 + " baugette(s) available."
```

must be

```
"We have " + amount1 + " baugette(s) available."
```

Consider using meaningful names for your variables, e.g. amountBaugettesInStore. This way you don't mix them up so easily.